# How to make common function in angularjs factory method

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using angularjs factory method for return data and I am passing that value to controllers.

- ) Instead of creating different function  need to create one common function and I want to return in all controllers.
- ) How to use repeated code in common function.
- ) scope.firstCard is having 15 records, scope.secondCard is having 6 records, scope.thirdCard is having 130 recods and scope.fourthCard is having 5 records. So everything is having different values.

Please look at my below factory code.

```js
app.factory('commonService', ['$timeout', '$rootScope', '$state', '$window',
        function($timeout, $rootScope, $state, $window) {
        
var renderData1 = function(scope) {
                var convertedTime = scope.firstCard.forEach(function(card) {
                    if (card.Category == 'A') {
                        console.log("A");
                    } else if (card.Category == 'B') {
                        console.log("B");
                    } else if (card.Category == 'C') {
                        console.log("C");
                    } else if (card.Category == 'D') {
                        console.log("D");
                    } else if (card.Category == 'E') {
                        console.log("E");
                    }
                });
                return convertedTime;
            };
            var renderData2 = function(scope) {
                var convertedTime = scope.secondCard.forEach(function(card) {
                    if (card.Category == 'A') {
                        console.log("A");
                    } else if (card.Category == 'B') {
                        console.log("B");
                    } else if (card.Category == 'C') {
                        console.log("C");
                    } else if (card.Category == 'D') {
                        console.log("D");
                    } else if (card.Category == 'E') {
                        console.log("E");
                    }
                });
                return convertedTime;
            }

           
            var renderData3 = function(scope) {
                var convertedTime = scope.thirdCard.forEach(function(card) {
                    if (card.Category == 'A') {
                        console.log("A");
                    } else if (card.Category == 'B') {
                        console.log("B");
                    } else if (card.Category == 'C') {
                        console.log("C");
                    } else if (card.Category == 'D') {
                        console.log("D");
                    } else if (card.Category == 'E') {
                        console.log("E");
                    }
                });
                return convertedTime;
            }

            var renderData4 = function(scope) {
                var convertedTime = scope.fourthCard.forEach(function(card) {
                    if (card.Category == 'A') {
                        console.log("A");
                    } else if (card.Category == 'B') {
                        console.log("B");
                    } else if (card.Category == 'C') {
                        console.log("C");
                    } else if (card.Category == 'D') {
                        console.log("D");
                    } else if (card.Category == 'E') {
                        console.log("E");
                    }
                });
                return convertedTime;
            }

            return {
                renderData1: renderData1,
                renderData2: renderData2,
                renderData3: renderData3,
                renderData4: renderData4

            };
            }]);
```

Instead of this. I want to create one function and I need to return it in multiple controllers. How can I do this.

```js
                        if (card.Category == 'A') {
                            console.log("A");
                        } else if (card.Category == 'B') {
                            console.log("B");
                        } else if (card.Category == 'C') {
                            console.log("C");
                        } else if (card.Category == 'D') {
                            console.log("D");
                        } else if (card.Category == 'E') {
                            console.log("E");
                        }
```

This condition is common for most of the controllers. So is this possible to use it in one place?

Answer (score 0):

you can create a service or factory and you can call that in all of your controllers

like this example

```
app.factory('commmonService', ['$timeout', function($timeout){
    return {
        firstFunction: function(param1){
            console.log(param1)

        },
        secondFunction: function(param1, param2){

        }
    }
}])

app.controller('myController', ['$scope', 'commmonService', function($scope, commmonService){

    $scope.myMethod = function(){
        commmonService.firstFunction('Hello');
    }
}])
```

Comment: What about that if condition? I am returning API response based on the category. In each condition has seperate app Variables.

Comment: @sathishkumar you must only pass you necessary parameters to service's function and retrieve result in all controllers. but you cannot pass scope as parameter you must pass parameters under the scope

Comment: @sathishkumar can you create an example with https://codesandbox.io/signin ? then I can adjust your code